# Passing value of button to next page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. 
I want to pass value of button from page 1 to *update* a php variable`($x)` in page 2 and *open page 2*
below is my code:

**page 1**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Userhome/chapter');?>
<button type="submit"  name="chapval" value="1" class="btn btn-info">Chapter1</button>
<button type="submit"  name="chapval" value="2" class="btn btn-info">Chapter2</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**controller**

```
class Userhome extends CI_Controller {
    public function chapter()
{
    $data5['chapter'] = $this->input->post('chapval', TRUE);

    $this->load->view('user/lesson',$data5);
}}
```

**Page2**

`<?php $x=$data5; ?>`

I want to get values 1 or 2 in `$x` and open page 2.

Comment: Hello @Lalit K welcome to SO. Why ain't you enabling jquery?

Comment: I can write the code in jQuery for you. if you want help do let me know!

Comment: @Ramsha Saeeda  Please help with that

Comment: In Page2, you can get `chapval` value like `<?php echo isset($chapter)?$chapter:'-'; ?>`

Comment: @Viren its just  printing "-" and not the values.

Comment: In controller, can you debug like `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die();` and check if you are getting `chapter` value or not.

Comment: @Viren I am not getting the values `Array
(
    [chapter] => 
)`

Comment: @Viren  sorry, getting  values now `Array
(
    [chapval] => 1
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, you are already getting the value in `$_POST` and as you said

> I want to get values 1 or 2 in `$x` and open page 2.

Instead of `<?php $x=$data5; ?>`, do `<?php $x=$chapter; ?>`

When you load the array variable `$data5` in the view, it extracts all the elements in the view, `chapter` in your case.